# How do you properly update relational data in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am creating an app that grabs kill events and then organizes who helped each other throughout the game and how many times someone killed someone, etc.

`assistingParticipantIds` can have anywhere from 0 to 4 ids

In team, assisted is how many times the player assisted that teammate.

In enemies, `kills` is how many times that player killed that player, `deaths` is how many times you died to him. `assistedKills` is when the player assisted in a kill for that player. `assistedDeaths` is when the player died to someone and that player assisted in his death.

**Example Entry:**

```
{ killerId: '125379794576736257',
  victimId: '167080722970968064',
  assistingParticipantIds: [ '276248160546979840', '136144690067013632' ] }
```

**Example Player:**

```
{ id: '142068805416255490',
  team:
   [ { id: '167080722970968064', assisted: 1 },
     { id: '255942275442409472', assisted: 1 },
     { id: '108332752302039040', assisted: 0 },
     { id: '290034993458053121', assisted: 3 } ],
  enemies:
   [ { id: '193758464231735296',
       kills: 0,
       assistedKills: 1,
       deaths: 0,
       assistedDeaths: 0 },
     { id: '125379794576736257',
       kills: 1,
       assistedKills: 0,
       deaths: 0,
       assistedDeaths: 0 },
     { id: '276248160546979840',
       kills: 0,
       assistedKills: 0,
       deaths: 0,
       assistedDeaths: 0 },
     { id: '121061410527641600',
       kills: 0,
       assistedKills: 0,
       deaths: 0,
       assistedDeaths: 0 },
     { id: '136144690067013632',
       kills: 0,
       assistedKills: 1,
       deaths: 0,
       assistedDeaths: 0 } ] }
```

I thought I had working code for this, but for some reason, some players will have more assists than they should.

```
events.forEach(event => {
  var killer = event.killerId
  var victim = event.victimId
  var assisted = event.assistingParticipantIds
  // p1 = player to update
  // p2 = relation to update
  // side = which side they are on
  // type = value to update
  function updatePlayer(p1, p2, side, type, players) {
    players.forEach(a => {
      if (a.id == p1) {
        a[side].forEach(b => {
          if (b.id == p2) {
            b[type]++
          }
        })
      }
    })
  }
  updatePlayer(killer, victim, "enemies", "kills", players)
  updatePlayer(victim, killer, "enemies", "deaths", players)
  if (assisted.length == 1) {
    updatePlayer(assisted[0], killer, "team", "assisted", players)
    updatePlayer(killer, assisted[0], "team", "assisted", players)
    updatePlayer(assisted[0], victim, "enemies", "assistedKills", players)
    updatePlayer(victim, assisted[0], "enemies", "assistedDeaths", players)
  } else if (assisted.length > 1) {
    assisted.forEach(assist => {
      updatePlayer(assist, killer, "team", "assisted", players)
      updatePlayer(killer, assist, "team", "assisted", players)
      updatePlayer(assist, victim, "enemies", "assistedKills", players)
      updatePlayer(victim, assist, "enemies", "assistedDeaths", players)
      assisted.forEach(c => {
        if (assist != c) {
          updatePlayer(assist, c, "team", "assisted", players)
        }
      })
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems mostly sound, but it's worth stepping through what, exactly, happens:

```
else if (assisted.length > 1) {
  assisted.forEach(assist => {
    updatePlayer(assist, killer, "team", "assisted", players)
    updatePlayer(killer, assist, "team", "assisted", players)
    updatePlayer(assist, victim, "enemies", "assistedKills", players)
    updatePlayer(victim, assist, "enemies", "assistedDeaths", players)
```

You iterate over the list of players that assisted in the kill. For each player, you:

- Increment the number of times the assister assisted the killer
- Increment the number of times the killer assisted the assister
- Increment the number of times the assister assisted in killing the victim
- Increment the number of times the victim was assisted in being killed by the assister

`assisted.forEach(c => {
      if (assist != c) {
        updatePlayer(assist, c, "team", "assisted", players)
      }
    })`

Then, for *every other assister*, you increment how many times the first assister assisted the second assister (god that word looks weird now).

This means that, if A kills E with the help of B, C, and D, the final stats will be:

- Player A has been assisted *three times* (+1 from B / C / D)
- Players B/C/D have been assisted *three times* (+2 from each other, +1 from A) and have *one assisted kill* against E
- Player E has *one assisted death* each from B, C, and D

So, A/B/C/D all have three assists. Without knowing exactly what you expected to happen, though, it's hard to comment on what the problem is.

If you expected B, C, and D to each get *one* assist, then you just need to strike out the second code block above.

If you expected A to get *no* assists, then you should strike out the line that adds assists to the killer.

Also, as an aside: you have code duplication going on here:

```
if (assisted.length == 1) {
    ...
  } else if (assisted.length > 1) {
    ...
    })
```

You can just throw out the first `if` statement and it should work exactly as before. It will iterate over the single assister, incrementing the four relevant stats, and then iterate over the single assister again. Since the sole assister equals itself, no additional stats will be modified.